# $f: V \rightarrow W$ linear transformation onto. There is a $g:W \rightarrow V$ linear transformation such that $f \circ g$ is identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

**Problem**. Let $V$ and $W$ vector space with finite dimension such that $f: V \rightarrow W$ linear transformation onto. There is a $g:W \rightarrow V$ linear transformation such that $f \circ g$ is identity.

We have, $f: V \rightarrow f[V]$ becuase $f$ is onto ($f(V)=W$). Then if we take $g:f(V) \rightarrow V$ such that $g(w)=f^{-1}(w)$. Then $f \circ g(v)= f \circ f^{-1}(v)=v$. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by $f^{-1}(w)$?

Comment: We have $f$is onto, then for all $w \in W$ exists $v \in V$ such that $f(v)=w$. So, $v=f^{-1}(w)$

Comment: @PSW Given $w \in W$, it is possible to exists at least two distinct $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $V$ such that $f(v_1)=w$ and $f(v_2)=w$. So, which one is $f^{-1}(w)$?

Comment: *Hint*: Use bases for $V$ and $W$.

Comment: so, $f^{-1}(w)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i}v_{i})$?

Comment: @PSW I don’t understand what that means. The symbol $f^{-1}(w)$ just does not have a well-defined meaning here. It has one when $f$ is also injective.

Comment: So, if I use bases for $V$ and $W$ we prove $f$ is injective right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138644/discussion-between-psw-and-azif00).

Comment: $f$ doesn't necessarily have to be injective. From rank-nullity you can prove that a linear map from a larger dimensional vector space to a smaller dimensional vector space can't be injective. But on the other hand, a linear map from a larger dimensional vector space to a smaller dimensional vector space can be surjective. Consider the map $T : R^2 \to R$ defined by $T(x, y)=x$. This is a surjective linear map, but it is not an injective linear map as $T(1, 2)=T(1, 3)$

Comment: I understand that $f$ is not necessarily injective. But, in your example. We can take $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $g(x)=(x,x)$ we have $T \circ g(x)=T(x,x)=x$ so $T \circ g $ is identity. Now, how can we generalize that idea.

Comment: Absolutely you can. Have a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint, to rigorize the idea you have:** Let $W$ have basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$, and pick $v_1,\dots,v_m\in V$ such that $f(v_i)=w_i$. Then the $\{v_i\}$ are linearly independent since any linear relation $\sum a_iv_i=0$ implies $\sum a_iw_i=0$, which contradicts the $\{w_i\}$ being linearly independent. Now, define $g\colon W\to V$ by $g(w_i):=v_i$. Check this is well-defined and satisfies the necessary conditions.

Comment: What is the need to say that the $v_i$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Right, that's unnecessary. The $v_i$'s being linearly independent shows $g$ is injective.